# Meteor Collection FS thumbnails not showing

Tags: meteor

I need assistance here

I am trying to create thumbnails using following example

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#image-manipulation

I have defined following code in both/collections/common.js

```
 var createThumb = function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
 // Transform the image into a 10x10px thumbnail
 gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('10',   '10').stream().pipe(writeStream);
 };

 Images =new FS.Collection('images',{
 stores: [
 new FS.Store.FileSystem("thumbs", {transformWrite: createThumb }),
 new FS.Store.FileSystem('images',{path:'~/projectUploads'})
]
});
```

And on template I have this code

```
  {{#each images}}
  <div>
  <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{url store='thumbs'}}" alt="image"/></a>
   </div>
  {{/each}}
```

This show broken images. Also in my collection thumb copy says size=0

If I change above code with store="images" original image display

```
{{#each images}}
  <div>
  <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{url store='images'}}" alt="image"/></a>
   </div>
  {{/each}}
```

What I am doing wrong? Any help really appreciate. I am stuck with it from last couple of days

[image]

Comment: does your images {{#each images }} template helper return Images FS - collection?

Comment: where do the broken images point to? Did you add the cfs:graphicsmagick package and have GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick installed?

Comment: @bya yes it return. I have call images.find() in helper.
Sander yes I have installed cfs:GraphicMagick

Comment: I just want to show thumnail instead of real big images. Images are showing but I think thumbs are not creating..Not sure why though it seems pretty simple from code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add a publication (server code):

```
Meteor.publish("images", function() {
    return Images.find({});
});
```

Allow rules (server code):

```
Images.allow({
    download: function(userId, doc) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Add a template helper "images" (client):

```
Template.your_template_name_here.helpers({
    images: function() {
        return Images.find()
    }
});
```

Comment: I am still waiting for solution. I am on windows 8. I have installed it  from here.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/

I think I was missing this. Is any other thing require to install? How I can check gm is working on my machine?

Comment: check if gm is avail by running gm.isAvailable ...
log to console on meteor.startup , meteor.call whatever...
you should also install the package cfs:filesystem